# FrameworkEvent ERROR coming in new installation of Eclipse Indigo

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, equinox

I'm getting following error in new Eclipse Indigo installation:

Exception Stack Trace:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: State change in progress for bundle "reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins_1.1.100.v20110510.jar" by thread "Start Level Event Dispatcher".
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.beginStateChange(AbstractBundle.java:1087)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.suspend(AbstractBundle.java:563)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.suspendBundle(Framework.java:1161)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.PackageAdminImpl.suspendBundle(PackageAdminImpl.java:327)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.PackageAdminImpl.processDelta(PackageAdminImpl.java:468)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.PackageAdminImpl.doResolveBundles(PackageAdminImpl.java:253)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.PackageAdminImpl$1.run(PackageAdminImpl.java:173)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle$BundleStatusException
... 8 more
Root exception:
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle$BundleStatusException
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.beginStateChange(AbstractBundle.java:1087)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.suspend(AbstractBundle.java:563)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.suspendBundle(Framework.java:1161)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.PackageAdminImpl.suspendBundle(PackageAdminImpl.java:327)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.PackageAdminImpl.processDelta(PackageAdminImpl.java:468)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.PackageAdminImpl.doResolveBundles(PackageAdminImpl.java:253)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.PackageAdminImpl$1.run(PackageAdminImpl.java:173)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Has any body come across this error? Please let me know.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I also cam across same error message **FrameworkEvent ERROR**. But exception stack trace is a bit different.

Comment: I also cam across same error message **FrameworkEvent ERROR**. But exception stack trace is a bit different. `org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.m2e.wtp [588]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime; bundle-version="[1.6.0,2.0.0)"
`. I was getting this issue while opening from Start Window shortcut but when I opened eclipse using **eclipse.exe** which is placed inside eclipse root folder, I didn't get this issue at all. Eclipse started without any error. I hope this solution might work for someone.